# Extract integers with white space from a string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I am very new at regex, so I am struggling with my code.

I have a dataframe, `df`, structured like this:

```
                                    NAME  PERCENT
0     APPLE COMPANY A  57 638 232 stocks  0.12322
1  BANANA 1 COMPANY B  12 946 201 stocks  0.02768
2     ORANGE COMPANY C  8 354 229 stocks  0.01786

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ['APPLE COMPANY A  57 638 232 stocks', 'BANANA 1 COMPANY B  12 946 201 stocks', 'ORANGE COMPANY C  8 354 229 stocks'],
    'PERCENT': [0.12322, 0.02768 , 0.01786]
    })
```

I want to extract the integers from `NAME`, but not all integers (note that in row 1 we have `BANANA 1 COMPANY B` where I want to ignore the integer `1` before `COMPANY`. I want to extract only those integers before `stocks`.

I want the output to look like this:

```
                 NAME  PERCENT    STOCKS
0     APPLE COMPANY A  0.12322  57638232
1  BANANA 1 COMPANY B  0.02768  12946201
2    ORANGE COMAPNY C  0.01786   8354229
```

So far I only have this, which doesn't produce what I want:

```
df['NAME'].str.findall(r'\b\d+\b')
```

Edit: Note that the number of stocks may change from thousands to millions, meaning that there is no pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `regex` will extract what are you looking for

```
\d+\s\d+\s\d+
```

**Matchs:**

```
57 638 232

12 946 201

8 354 229
```

**From :**

```
'NAME': ['APPLE COMPANY A  57 638 232 stocks', 'BANANA 1 COMPANY B  12 946 201 stocks', 'ORANGE COMPANY C  8 354 229 stocks']
```

Comment: so totally: `df['Stocks']=df['NAME'].str.findall(r'\b\d+\b').apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))` and  `df.NAME=df.NAME.replace('\d{1,}\s\d+\s\d+','',regex=True).str.strip('stocks ')` should do it. Nice one, +1

Comment: @anky_91 is it possible to extract all integers? I have integers like `500`, `8 000` and `10 000` as well, not just in the million interval.

Comment: `(\d+\s\d+\s\d+)|(\d+\s\d{3})|(\d{2,})` this will match 500, 8 000 and 10 000